# Function to lambda expression

Tags: lambda, kotlin, data-class

I have a data class and I need to initialize some `List<String>`. I need to get the values of a JsonArray (I'm using Gson).

I made this function:

```
private fun arrayToList(data: JsonArray, key: String): List<String> {
    val list = mutableListOf<String>()

    data.forEach { a ->
        list.add(a[key].asString)
    }

    return list
}
```

How can I convert to work as a lambda expression?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're looking for the `map` operation:

```
data.map { a -> a[key].asString }
```

Or you can use the default parameter name `it`:

```
data.map { it[key].asString }
```

Answer (score 3):

If you use the `map` function, you can write this as a single expression...

```
private fun arrayToList(data: JsonArray, key: String): List<String> = 
    data.map { it[key].asString }
```

The `map` function takes an argument of one type and turns it into another. I'm also taking advantage of the fact that the default element name in Kotlin is called `it`, so I don't have to define something explicitly like I would in (say) Java. So what this says is "for each object in `data`, get the `key` value and call `.asString` on it. This is automatically converted to a `List`.

Comment: Thank you very much too!